# Is there a way to have/mimic property for the object of a class itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I could set a property of the object itself, however, due to various design implementations, this wouldn't work (I have done this already, and it updates other attributes and then returns 'self', so that I can use the methods already defined for that object).

I don't know if it would be possible, but initiating the constructor every time the object is accessed also would not be practical, because there's quite a lot of initiate, so it would really only be for a few select attributes.

I could simply hard code a method that resets the desired attributes where and if needed, but this would be cumbersome.

What would really be needed is to call a method automagically every time the object itself is accessed so that I don't have to do so manually.

To give an example of what I need, I've coded up some pseudo-code. The actual code is much more complex:

```
class Substick:
    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.end - self.start


    @property
    def sub2(self):
        self.start = 25
        self.end = 50
        return self

    @property
    def sub1(self):
        self.start = 0
        self.end = 67
        return self



    def quad(self, quadrant):
        num = quadrant*(self.length)/4
        return num

    def half(self):
        num = (self.length)/2
        return num
```

Above is the class, called Stick. Very simply, the class is a stick (well the object, but again it's just example code), that has length 1-100. There are two methods, half and quad, half returns half the length, quad return a cetain fraction of the stick, specified by the argument quadrant – quadrant/4 –.

There is sub1 and sub2, which are subsections of the stick, and thus have different start and endpoints. When they are called, the attributes get updated, and self is returned so that the methods of the class can be used with the updated values.

This is all fine and good, but the problem here is that there's no way to change the start and endpoints of the stick back to the original length as it was when the object was first initiated.

Again, this is pseudo-code. Simply setting an attribute called 'main', for e.g stick.main, wouldn't really work, for reasons that would be too complex to go into with respect to the real code.

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: Surely images are more clear? Copying and pasting the code in wouldn't be as well-formatted.

Comment: @JimJam Not to people using screen readers. Please use text. We don't need colors and italics and whatever other highlighting your editor is providing.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be as well formatted? SO's has a built-in code highlighter.

Comment: But it would turn out like this. class Substick:
    '@property
    def length(self):
        return self.end - self.start


    '@property
    def sub2(self):
        self.start = 25
        self.end = 50
        return self

    '@property
    def sub1(self):

Comment: @Barmar what's a code highlighter?

Comment: Ahhh I see. Ok thanks for the adivce.

Comment: It adds styling to the code block to make different parts stand out.

Comment: Like coloring `@property` in red.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the edit ^_^

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you need, but `sub1` and `sub2` should probably *not* be modifying the original object. They can return new `Stick` instances, or they can return a new "view" of the original instance, but more information about how `Stick` is used would be needed to provide the right design.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. But actually it's intended to do exactly that. I'm working with databases, and it's split up into various sections. So you have the database itself, that can modify itself via various methods, but then you have sections of that database which can modify the overall database by utilizing the same methods, but with different input and different ways (but again, all still using the exact same methods).

Comment: It's hard, because I can't simply have the database outside the class, because I'll need more than one database (if it was a single database this would be fine). I can't inherit, because then they won't have access to the same database. I can't use properties, because then the attributes of the main database can't get reset back.

Comment: Think of it like this, in the example code for the Stick class, there might be a method called 'notch'. If you access a subsection of the stick, and you make a notch in it, it's still on the stick itself, overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, you have a core bit of data (a database, but analogized to a stick in the question), and you need to be able to easily operate on different subsets of it.

The best way to do this is probably to make a "view" class that lets you treat the subset as if it was a whole database/stick transparently. It will have the API of the core object, but won't hold the data itself, rather it will just translate things to work on the main object it was built from.

It would be something like this:

```
class Stick:
    """Class to hold some data."""
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.start = 0
        self.end = len(data)

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.end - self.start

class SubStick(Stick):
    """Thin wrapper around a real Stick. SubStick's don't hold data themselves."""
    def __init__(self, stick, start, end):
        self.stick = stick
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.stick.data[self.start:self.end]
```

Now you can create and use Substick objects in the same way as you use the Stick:

```
stick = Stick([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(stick.data, stick.length) # [1, 2, 3, 4] 4

s1 = SubStick(stick, 0, 2)
print(s1.data, s1.length) # [1, 2] 2

s2 = SubStick(stick, 2, 4)
print(s2.data, s2.length) # [3, 4] 2
```

If you want to, you could add properties to the `Stick` class that return specific `SubStick` instances. That seems like a slightly strange API, but it might be convenient in your real code in some way that's not obvious from the stick analogy.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. You don't pass in the content itself to the sub sticks, but you pass in the information that it needs to reference the original stick, as well as attributes of the sub stick itself. That's smart, I was trying to define a subclass (a class inside of the main class), but working with one outside is much better. Thank you :)

Comment: That may be a terminology issue then. In my example, `SubStick` is a subclass of `Stick` (which means it inherits some things, like the `length` property). A class defined within another class is a different thing, I'd probably call it a "nested" class. It's possible to define a nested class that is also a subclass, just because of how Python's class definitions work (the name of the base class won't be defined yet when an inner class tries to use it).